# V.S 2008 Reporting

Tags: c#, reporting

I'm using visual studio 2008 with c#. i want to show that  result of query on my column chart.
My query is:

```
select (select count(cinsiyeti) 
from Hastalar where cinsiyeti = 'E') AS ERKEK , 
(select count(cinsiyeti) from Hastalar where cinsiyeti = 'K') AS KADIN
```

I get values and dataset name. values: =Fields!Erkek.Value and =Fields!Kadin.Value

but the compiler give that error:

**The Label expression for the chart ‘cCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi’ refers to the field ‘Erkek’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current data set scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified data set scope. C:\Users\cagin_arslan\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\RaporCalisamalari\RaporCalisamalari\rptCinsiyeteGoreHastaSayisi.rdlc    RaporCalisamalari**

Answer (score 0):

As long as your variable names match in the datatable in your dataset and with the returns of your sql statement it should be fine. Like yieldvs said it may be a case issue.